# How to display a dialog fragment in almost full screen in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment and a createView of

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zse_dialog, container,false);

    return view;
}
```

I call the fragment with

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            DialogF dialogFragment = new DialogF ();
            dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment");

            return false;
        }
    });
```

but it seems compressed in the center of the screen.

How I am to make it show in full screen or almost in full screen with a margin

Answer (score 0):

If you have a container on your activity where to show the DialogFragment, you can add it as a regular fragment, like this

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container, new MyFragment(), "fragment_tag")
    .commit();
```

Comment: What do you mean by Container, I have a fragment which has an expandable listview as I mentioned above

Comment: I mean a ViewGroup like a FrameLayout. You could add a FrameLayout to your layout, initially with visibility GONE, then when you want to show the dialog you set the visibility to VISIBLE and load the dialog fragment onto it.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your style

```
    <style name="FullScreenDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    </style>
// the android:layout_margin is what you can use to adjust the view
```

and add this to your DialogFragment

```
 @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.FullScreenDialog;
    }
```